# How to detect who is consuming permanently space on Hard Disk

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, memory, disk-space

My System Disk "C:\", where is installed Win7x64 OS has 80 GB. I hah last time free space 8 GB, after uninstalling some apps and cleanup Disk, BUT every day disk free space is varying from 8 to 1 GB, while basically from that PC it's internet surfing performed (no by me).

Concrete case: I see there 1 GB, after restart 3-4 GB, then after some hours again 1 GB, then it may be even less or again up to 8GB.

HOW TO detect who is consuming disk pace - maybe some tool, utility which collect statistics and show in real-time and historically who what consumed on Hard Disk?

UPDATE: RAM = 4 GB

Comment: Do you use MS Outlook with an exchange server by chance?

Comment: no. Mainly Firefox, chrome and RDP on other PCs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your pagefile is set to automatically resize and is resizing due to memory pressure.

You can either go through the control panel to view the pagefile settings or open a Powershell console and use `Get-CimInstance Win32_PageFileUsage | Select *`

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's really automatically? 
But is it recommend to be changed?

Comment: If it's using the pagefile that much I would recommend adding more memory. Note that you could track what files get written by using a tool like ProcMon from Sysinternals. That way you can verify it really is Pagefile.sys or some other file(s).

Comment: In the old days, it was recommended to set the pagefile to a fixed value *(double the size of your memory)*. Today, I really don't bother with that anymore. As soon as I notice the pagefile getting used to much, I either don't have enough memory and add some or an application is misbehaving and I'll try to track that down and remove or fix *(update)* it.