# Check why my hard disk always has no free space

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I have Windows 10. Recently I came across a very strange problem: my hard disk is always full. I keep constantly deleting files from it, removing 2-3 GB, but it gets back with 0 Mb free again and again. How could I check (maybe with some utility) where the free space goes? I scanned my computer with antivirus, but nothing was found.

Comment: 2 - 3 GB is nowhere near enough free space on a drive, even a small one. Aim for 10-% or 10 - 20 GB.

Comment: What size is your disk? Where is the data concentrated? It it all your personal data or is it system files? We need more details.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/687625/how-to-detect-who-is-consuming-permanently-space-on-hard-disk https://superuser.com/questions/1180629/low-disk-space-on-drive-c-with-windows-10?rq=1

Comment: [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net) may be of interest.

Comment: Actually, it was a miner, which consumed more and more space for some purposes.

Comment: @newt You're welcome. Glad you got it figured out. =)